# Pygame : Rollback when using pygame.time.Clock() and FPS

Tags: python, pygame, lag, frame-rate, rollback

I have a problem of rollback on many of my pygame projects. When I use  pygame.time.Clock(FPS) at the end of my code, the entity i move has rollback ( the movement of the character is not smooth as it should be ) . I try without the pygameclock but now my character is moving too fast . I also add the convert at the end of the pygame.load.image but no difference at all ... What can I do ? No matter the number of FPS, rollback still there ... There is my code :

> ```
> import pygame from pygame.locals import *
>
> pygame.init()
>
> screen_width = 1000 
> screen_height = 1000
>
> FPS = 60 
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
>
>
> screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
> pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')
>
> tile_size = 50
>
> sun_img = pygame.image.load('sun.png').convert_alpha() 
> bg_img = pygame.image.load('sky.png').convert()
>
>
> class Player():
>    def __init__(self,x,y):
>     img = pygame.image.load('guy1.png').convert_alpha()
>     self.image = pygame.transform.scale(img,(40,80))
>     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
>     self.rect.x = x
>     self.rect.y = y
>
> def update(self):
>
>     dx = 0
>     dy = 0
>
>     # ket pressed
>     key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
>     if key[K_LEFT]:
>         dx -= 5
>     if key[K_RIGHT]:
>         dx += 5
>
>     # check for collisions
>
>     # update player position
>
>     self.rect.x += dx
>     self.rect.x += dy
>
>
>
>
>
>
>     screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
>
>
> class World():
> def __init__(self, data):
>     self.tile_list = []
>
>     
>     dirt_img = pygame.image.load('dirt.png').convert()
>     grass_img = pygame.image.load('grass.png').convert()
>
>     row_count = 0
>     for row in data:
>         col_count = 0
>         for tile in row:
>             if tile == 1:
>                 img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
>                 img_rect = img.get_rect()
>                 img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
>                 img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
>                 tile = (img, img_rect) # tuple avec l'image et ses coordonnées
>                 self.tile_list.append(tile)
>             if tile == 2:
>                 img = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
>                 img_rect = img.get_rect()
>                 img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
>                 img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
>                 tile = (img, img_rect)
>                 self.tile_list.append(tile)
>             col_count += 1
>         row_count += 1
>
> def draw(self):
>     for tile in self.tile_list:
>         screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1]) # tile[0] = l'image / tile[1] = les coordonnées
>
>
>
> world_data = [
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ]
>
> player = Player(100,screen_height - 130) world = World(world_data)
>
> run = True 
> while run:
>
>
> screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
> screen.blit(sun_img, (100, 100))
>
> world.draw()
> player.update()
>
> for event in pygame.event.get():
>     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>         run = False
>
>
> pygame.display.update()
> clock.tick(FPS)
>
>
>
>
> pygame.quit()
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "rollback"? I cannot reproduce this behavior. In this program the just moves to the left and right.

Comment: Like if i move the character to the right, then each 0.30 secondes the character will move back a little bit and then go again to the position he was, and vise versa for going left

Comment: Sorry but this issue is not reproducible. If there is an issue, it is related to your IDE but not to your program.

Comment: I'm using pycharm ... Thanks you anyway.